# The encryption scheme is secure?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, semantic-security

I have a scheme and I don't know that this scheme is semantic security or not.

**Secret keys** $\{s_1,s_2, x_1,x_2\}$ and **public parameter** $p$ (large prime number).
**Encryption** E(m): $C_1 = s_1m + x_1k \bmod p$ and $C_2 = s_2m + x_2k \bmod p$ where $k$ is pseudo-random number.

Comment: And how do you decrypt it?  Or, is how $k$ is generated also part of the key?

Comment: $k$ is a pseudo-random number as the output of one-way function e.g., $k \leftarrow F_K(id_m)$ where $K$ is a secret key and $id_m$ is an identify of message $m$. Thanks.

Comment: If $k$ is pseudorandom and not truly random, this is not a one-time pad. OTP is a *very* specific cryptosystem; if you don't have a truly random key which is never used for more than one message, you don't have it.

Comment: Ok, thanks @cpast, I edited the title of question. It is not OTP, I mean this scheme is very similar to the OTP encryption.

Comment: You can't say "pseudorandom as output of one-way function". You can say "pseudorandom as output of pseudorandom function".

Comment: @poncho By substituting some fixed private key and ciphertext, the equations defining $C_1$ and $C_2$ yield a linear system over $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ in two indeterminates $m$, $k$. This system can be efficiently solved to obtain the original message $m$.

Answer (score 2):

*(**Note:** This answer is based on $k$ being generated by applying a pseudorandom function to a unique message-ID – counter – each time.)*

It depends how many times you want to encrypt with it.

If you want it as a complicated OTP, then it's secure. In order to see this, just ignore the $x$ parts and note that $s_1m \bmod p$ and $s_2m \bmod p$ are to independent encryptions under random keys $s_1,s_2$ (note that $s_1$ and $s_2$ have to be uniform in $\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$. For this, you don't need $p$ to be large (just big enough to contain $m$).

If you want to encrypt many times, then it is certainly no longer information theoretically secure. However, just ignore $s_1,x_1,s_2,x_2$ and think of them as public constants. Then, you are encrypting by $m+k \bmod p$ where $k$ is pseudorandomly generated. This is like a type of "counter mode". As long as the RANGE of the pseudorandom function is $\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ you should be able to prove it.

In both cases, it is overly complicated…

Comment: "Also, the question should" ... $\;$